# "Pass", "Pas through" and "Move through"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request, sentence-structure

Please imagine a bully boy in a school stands intentionally in front of another student and doesn't let him get out of the door or pass a way. Which one of the following sentences would work in both "door" and "path" ways:

> - He stood in my way and didn’t let me pass.
> - He stood in my way and didn’t let me [pass through](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+through).
> - He stood in my way and didn’t let me [move through](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/move+through).

If no one of the bold verbs above works naturally, then please let me know what shall i use instead?

P.S. in my language there is just one single verb which can be used for both situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the word **through** it literally means to go through **something**. This is clear from both of the definitions that you linked to. The only place or thing mentioned in your sentence is **He**, obviously the you don't want to literally go through him... starting at the mouth and coming out at the butt, or any other way... and he probably doesn't want you to go through him either.

You can pass through countryside, or a city, or a doorway, but you can't pass through a person. The only sensible sentence is the first one:

> He stood in my way and didn’t let me pass.

If you replace **didn't** by **wouldn't** (the past tense of **won't**) you make it clear that standing in your way was an act of will: he deliberately stopped you from passing.

> He stood in my way and wouldn’t let me pass.

Comment: In this case through would work as it would be implied that the student wants to go through the door, or through to their destination. "He wouldn't let me through (the door)."

Comment: @JamesP, If it were stated that the bully were standing in the doorway, yes. But there is no mention of a doorway, or any other location, in the sentence. **pass** works under all circumstances: **pass through** would only work if it were stated that the bully were standing in some confined space.